# How to get the Title of inner frame in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, browser-automation

In my program, I am trying to get the Title of the inner frame by switching the driver control to inner frame with the help of getTitle() method. But,it is still return the title of main page.
please find the below bit of code I tried with

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("url");
driver.switchTo().frame("frame name/id");
driver.getTitle();
```

Is there any way to get the Title of the inner frame in selenium webdriver using Java.

Comment: `getTitle()` method looks for the `<title>` tag in the HTML and returns whatever it's there. Does your frame has a `<title>` tag? Please post the complete html of the page.

Comment: Yes, it has <title> tag in <head> tag of the frame. though I can't post my full html code here, I can provide the overview of how it looks <iframe id="xxx" width="xxx" Style="xxxx" >

Comment: disregard my previous reply.
Yes, it has <title> tag in <head> tag of the frame. though I can't post my full html code here, I can provide the overview of how it looks 
<iframe id="xxx" width="xxx" Style="xxxx" >   
  <html>  
    <head> 
      <title> xxxxxxx</title>
    </head>
   <body> 
       some element related tags within the frame 
   </body> 
  </html>  
</iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below code to achieve the same

```
// before switching frame

driver.getTitle(); 
//or

driver.find_element_by_tag_name("title").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

and after switching frame

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame name/id");
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("title").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Hope This will help as I'm able to do the same using this code

Comment: Yes, it worked as expected. Thank you..
if you don't think it is too much to ask, may I ask one more question like what exactly getAttribute() method retrieves? what is the purpose of it?

Comment: `getAttribute()` method in selenium allows us to get the attribute value of particular tag . e.g. I have one  anchor tag `<a id="123456" class="testclass" />` and if you wanted to get the value `testclass` of class attribute the you can use this method like `getAttribute("class");`

Comment: Thank you for the information. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, I get the correct frame title:

```cs
//store all frames
var frames = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));

//loop through frames
foreach (var frame in frames)
{
     //just do debug
     Console.WriteLine(frame.GetAttribute("title"));
}

//do your thing...
```

Comment: I don't see the C# tag in the question, or any mention of C# as a solution language. SO why post a C# solution?

Comment: I most cases, this questions about "selenium" have comments with C#, Java, or Python to solve a specific problem. I am just trying help.